# Getting a URL from an open browser

Tags: ruby, selenium, url, browser

I am trying to get the URL from an active Chrome browser window. I expect output like `https://www.google.pl/` when I have the Google page enabled. I want to download the address from a browser that is already running.

With C++, I can only search for an active window and its title. It will be easier using Ruby and Selenium, but I can only return a window URL that the script will turn on.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path="drivers/chromedriver.exe"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get("http://www.google.com") # So, without it.
puts driver.current_url
```

Can I change it to get a URL from the previously enabled window? Is it possible with Ruby? Or maybe someone has an idea for my problem in another language?

Comment: what is the goal here? You can use a userscript or browser extension much easier

Comment: I wanted to do it using a locally running program or script. I did not even think about adding a plugin - is there a way to add a google chrome extension to C ++, for example?

Comment: no, I mean like a chrome or firefox extension, it's written in JS

Comment: I understand, I wonder if I will later have the option to "install" it with, for example, C ++

Comment: This is not possible using Selenium , you can check it here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, you can't attach the existing window(window which was already opened) using Selenium-webdriver. It's possible in WATIR-Classic but it only works for IE, it's not available for firefox or for chrome. But when you use Selenium or WATIR(wrapper around selenium) you can't switch to the new window if new window has been opened as the result of the click in the first window. Or you can open the chrome in the specific portal and that window you can connect with but that's not possible for firefox. But remember what you are asking for is attaching the window which has already been opened and it's not possible in Selenium.

Comment: Ok, thank you for such a detailed explanation.